# How to set automatically optimize code of template function in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have wondered about template optimizing. Look at the sample code:

```
....
template <class T>
T AReallyBigFunction(T); //size = a (MB)
....
int main(){
   ....
   short number1;
   int number2;
   long number3;
   cout << AReallyBigFunction(number1) << endl;
   cout << AReallyBigFunction(number2) << endl;
   cout << AReallyBigFunction(number3) << endl;
   ....
}
```

The question is: All three of `number1`, `number2` and `number3` always give the correct result with `AReallyBigFunction<long>`, but I don't want to notice to template parameter `long` and I don't want to multiply unneccessary program size, Does gcc/g++ can do it?

**EDIT**

size of `AReallyBigFunction<T>` equal to a MB for each `class T`. So, If call `AReallyBigFunction` with three various integer type, total size is 3*a MB. If I always call `AReallyBigFunction<long>` (with template parameter `class T` has been specified to `long`), the size is a MB. I want the compiler always calls `AReallyBigFunction<long>` although I just write `AReallyBigFunction` (without specifying `class T`, with any integer value (`short`, `int` or `long`)). My question is: does gcc/g++ has any solution (compiling mode) to respond me?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think I understand this.  A compiler may implement `int` and `long` as equivalent types.  And you're asking if the linker maintains separate functions for both if they happen to produce the same machine code?

Comment: If you're saying that `AReallyBigFunction` can be implemented once with a `long` parameter and gives correct results when `int` and `short` are promoted to a `long` for the call then just have your template class inherit from a non-template base and implement `AReallyBigFunction` (and any other methods that don't depend on the template parameter) in it.

Answer (score 2):

If the comment by @DrewDormann is correct interpretation of the question, then you can use the following trick to reduce code size.

Define function overloads that take an `int` and `short` and call the function template using `long`.

```
int AReallyBigFunction(int in)
{
   long res = AReallyBigFunction<long>(in);
   return static_cast<int>(res);
}

short AReallyBigFunction(short in)
{
   long res = AReallyBigFunction<long>(in);
   return static_cast<short>(res);
}
```

Comment: I know this way. However, If I have many functions like `AReallyBigFunction`, I don't want to define each overload of them